# Header information's not passing for cross domain request

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, authorization, cross-domain

I have made one API application, and using jQuery ajax I am trying to get data from API. But I am getting error 401: Authorization Error. Later I found the header Authorization is not passing with request, so API cannot able to track it. Below is the code which I used for my application. Please help me...

PHP Code:

```
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Orgin: *");
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: *");
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Authorization, X-Requested-With, Content-Type");
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true");
```

jQuery Code:

```
$.ajax({
    type: method,
    url: url,
    dataType: 'JSONP',
    crossDomain: true,
    headers: {'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'},
    beforeSend: function (xhr){ 
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', "Basic xxxx"); 
    },
    success: function (){
        alert('Thanks for your comment!'); 
    }
});
```

Comment: What is your type?  Should be post or get.

Comment: Sorry for adding this question, the issue was misspelled header origin... :)